# ImageView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `MainActivity.java` I have a sort of button to login. I also have 4 fragments, each of them containing a recycler view (imageview + textview).
The imageview is hidden, but when I press the button it becomes visibile. How can I do that? The `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work in the adapter and I can't call it on the adapter in the fragment page, because is outside the `onCreateView` method.
Here's my code:

MainActivity: contains the button

Fragment Page:

```
public class Classici_Tab extends Fragment {

    LinkedList<Book> catalog = new LinkedList<>();

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    BookListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classici_tab, container, false);

        fillCatalog("catalog.csv");     //fill the LinkedList

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.classici_rv);
        mAdapter = new BookListAdapter(getContext(), catalog);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class BookListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookListAdapter.BookViewHolder> {

    // View Holder
    class BookViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public final ImageView cover;
        public final TextView title;
        public final TextView author;
        public final ImageView availability;
        final BookListAdapter mAdapter;

        public BookViewHolder(View itemView, BookListAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView);
            cover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            availability = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.availability);

            MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
            if(m.loggedin)  availability.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else            availability.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            this.mAdapter = adapter;
        }
    }

    private LinkedList<Book> mBookList = new LinkedList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    boolean isVisible = false;

    public BookListAdapter()    {}

    public BookListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<Book> bookList) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mBookList = bookList;
    }

    //IT DOESN'T WORK
    public void setPicturesVisibility(boolean isVisible){
        this.isVisible = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public BookViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BookViewHolder(mItemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BookViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.cover.setImageResource(mBookList.get(position).getCover());
        holder.title.setText(mBookList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.author.setText(mBookList.get(position).getAuthor());
        holder.availability.setImageResource(mBookList.get(position).getAvailability());

        if(isVisible){
            holder.availability.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.availability.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mBookList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to recreate adapter. You can add a boolean `arePicturesVisible = false;` in your RecyclerViewAdapter.
And make a method in adapter:

```
public void setPicturesVisibility(boolean areVisible){
    arePicturesVisible = areVisible;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then add:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    .....
    if(arePicturesVisible){
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    .....
}
```

Then in your button `onClick()` method call `setPicturesVisibility()` from RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... the "notifyDataSetChanged()" seems not being called

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to recreate adapter. Without recreating adapter, you can add listener to the button and in the onclick event handler, make image visible in recyclerview adapter's viewholder constructor.

```
public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textview = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);       
        imgView = view.findViewById(R.id.storeImg);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

You can find recyclerview examples here http://www.zoftino.com/android

Comment: as far as I understood he want to hide all pictures in all Views on button click

Comment: I thought button is part of item, if not your solution would work @DimDim

Comment: Lorenco wrote "I have a button and a recycler view (imageview + textview)", thats why I thought the button is outside of RecyrclerView